# ES6 javascript Subclass not inheriting all variables?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, es6-class

So basically I have an es6 js class where constructor variables are created then assigned within a class method.  Later I create a sub class that extends the first and pass all variables I wish to use to the subclass constructor and subsequently to the super method. After this one variable is correct and the other is undefined, both are created passed and logged in the same manner. Why would it be undefined??

```
class socket {
  constructor() {
    this.socket = {};
    this.base = '/*string*/';
    this.mainIndex;
    this.dashboard;
    this.user_id;
  }

  socket_start() {

    //do stuff here to start websocket

    self.socket.onmessage = function ( event ) {
      let stream = JSON.parse( event.data );
      this.mainIndex = stream.url.mainIndex; 
      this.dashboard = stream.url.dashboard; 
      this.user_id = stream.staffInfo.id; 
      this.base = stream.base;  

      console.log( this.user_id ); // "1"
      console.log( this.base); // "string"
    }
  }
}


class main extends socket {
  constructor( user_id, base, socket, mainIndex, dashboard ) {
  super( user_id, base, socket, mainIndex, dashboard );


  console.log( this.user_id ); // undefined   <--????
  console.log( this.base); // "string"
}
```

Comment: Your parent class constructor ignores all the arguments it is passed.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: sure, I posted an example as an answer below.

Comment: Your parent constructor does only create the `.socket` and `.base` properties by assignment. All the other properties are created later in that `onmessage` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent class ignores any arguments that it is passed. Compare the two versions below:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.name;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name)
  }
}

> new B("Hunter");
B {}
```

Now an example with the correct behavior:

```
class A {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name)
  }
}

> new B("Hunter");
B { name: 'Hunter' }
```

Comment: So why do all of the other variables passed work in my example except 1?

Comment: You set the value of `base` explicitly in your `socket` constructor, so it makes sense that it is defined in subclass `main`

Comment: Would `this.user_id = 0;` in socket class  - then change it in the method work then?

Comment: It would make it `0` all the time. What you really want is to accept the user_id that your subclass passes to the parent in its call to `super`.

Comment: My only concern is that I alter the variables within the methods of the class only, NOT on creation of the instance such as `let x = new main()` <-- nothing is passed here as an arg.  Does that matter?